# How do I load a modified python module?

Tags: serial-port, pip

I'm using the widely used module PySerial (http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/index.html#) for serial communication in Python. One of it's functions is readline() which reads a line until end of line '\n'. I created a new function readline_v2() similar to readline() in the same file serialutil.py. But each time I install the module using "python install setup.py", it seems as if none of the changes are reflected. The new function is not detected. What am I doing wrong?

I'm using Windows 8 64 bit. I first downloaded pyserial's source, uncompressed it, and modified it when I found it didn't work the way I wanted it to.

I tried it using pip also, using "pip install pyserial" but once again there is no change. I made sure I uninstalled the previous version before reinstalling. The files don't exist in the "C:/python27/lib/site-packages" folder after the uninstall. I also deleted all compiled/build files I saw in the serial package before reinstalling.

Note: In "C:/python27/lib/site-packages", after installation, I can see the change reflected in the specific file serialutil.py. But I still am unable to call the function.

Note2: serialutil.py consists of functions of the form-

> ```
> def readline()
> def readline_v2()
> ```

This is the only place I added my function since the original function readline() is  defined/used nowhere else.

Final Note: I can't find a fix. But I used a workaround. I defined the new function in my file after doing an "import serial", instead of modifying the package itself. Not the ideal solution, but it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the location of your new module to path with sys.path.append() or alternatively keep the new module in your project directory

Comment: I modified an existing module. I did not add anything new.

Comment: using pip will download a new copy and install that.  Using setup.py install should reflect your changes, though.  Is it possible they are not being made in the right place?  I don't know how simple or complex the module is offhand

Comment: What I have typically done when I want to modify a module is copy it all out of the python directory, modify it and import it from elsewhere.  I don't like having a modified one installed since I usually end up doing something in the future and then it doesn't act as expected.

Comment: pip can also be used with local copies using pip install -e path. In any case, each time I install, the modified version, it is clearly reflected in the files present at site-packages (which I believe is from where python imports). But despite the changes, when I import, I'm unable to use the new function.